# Does Expression<Func<T>> work with mixed static / instance members?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I'm using `GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> member)` to retrieve member names. When not using the `static` modifier for the `Foo` property, the member cannot be used with this method:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Program.Foo'

Since my level of understanding for LINQ Expressions is not that deep, I would like to ask:

**Question:** Is there a way, other than `nameof(Foo)` to access a member in an *"equivalent"* way? The goal is to get property metadata, like the name, rather than to access its value from the instance.

```
public class Program
{
    public /*static*/ int Foo { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetMemberName(() => Foo));
    }

    public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> member)
    {
        return (member.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  You suggested method would not work if there was more than one instance of the object.  the purpose of using instances is to you can have multiple copies of the object.

Comment: `Foo` => `default(Program).Foo`

Comment: To access non-static member you need some object to get it from there. I understand above is just an example but would it work if you request `this.Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the code inside `public`***static***`void Main(string[] args)`, meaning you don't have a `Program` instance to access the `Foo` **instance member**. It has nothing to do with expressions, `GetMemberName` will work as you wrote it regardless.